# kdb: filter table match symbol column: ~ vs =

Tags: kdb

For a `where` clause to filter on symbol columns, `=` works fine, but why does the match operator `~` not work?

```
q)t:([sym:`aa`bb]qty:20 30)

q)t
sym| qty
---| ---
aa | 20
bb | 30

q)select from t where sym=`aa
sym| qty
---| ---
aa | 20

q)select from t where sym~`aa
sym| qty
---| ---
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match is comparing `aa to the entire symbol column, where equals is comparing to each element

```
q)`a=`a`b`c
100b
q)`a~`a`b`c
0b
```

You could do

```
q)select from t where sym~\:`aa
sym| qty
---| ---
aa | 20
```